# Python-Selenium script opens Edge and IE both instead of Edge only

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

Given below is my code that reads from a JSON file. Opens a few URL and takes screenshot.

Problem is; First it opens Edge and for 2nd item onward it open IE. What am I doing wrong?

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.EDGE
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True

with open('path\sites.json', encoding='utf-8') as s:
    data = json.loads(s.read())

for site in data['sites']:
    driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\\Python37-32\\drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe', capabilities=caps)
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot path')

driver.close()
```

Comment: As a workaround try to move `driver` definition out of `for` loop to create WebDriver instance only once per script. Tip: also replace `driver.close()` with `driver.quit()`

Comment: @Andersson: Tried that. Still the same. I ran this same script With IE before and it worked fine. The only difference now is broswer change & driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The push was based on the application.
Some of the web applications had a hardcoded instruction to launch a separate browser i.e. Explorer. For example;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>HTA Test</title>
  <hta:application applicationname="HTA Test" scroll="yes" singleinstance="yes">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("Firefox http://www.google.com");
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Open Google in Firefox">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to lunch more than on Edge instance, and apparently it will stay like this in the foreseeable future. There is an open issue in [microsoft edge issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13618786/)

> Edge only allows one instance to be running for Web Driver testing. 
>   Perhaps with if/when Edge supports multiple profiles this capability
>   will also be added.
>
> I will close this as “working as designed.”

Either move the driver initialization outside the loop or close the browser at the end of each loop

```
driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\\Python37-32\\drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe', capabilities=caps)

for site in data['sites']:
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot path')

driver.quit()
```

or

```
for site in data['sites']:
    driver = webdriver.Edge('C:\\Python37-32\\drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe', capabilities=caps)
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot path')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Problem isn't that multiple instances of Edge are required. If I move driver.quit() into FOR Block then it will Close the edge and at any given time only one instance of Edge will be running. But the problem is; the script opens IE after opening edge! unsure why!